# Store Video in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing video related App in windows phone 8 and I am downloading the videos from server and store in Isolated storage.My problem is that if I download video in My device it should be visible in Windows phone as far as I know isolated storage is for particular app we can't access data saved in isolated storage Without activating App.

So please let me know how to access video downloaded from App without opening app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate your app with 'Music and Video' hub. More details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Can sample provided by microsoft run on Emulator?And pleas let me know one more thing that is submit app to Windows store is required to implement it?

Comment: I think you can test the app on Emulator. Follow above link, there is some explanation concerning a testig. Sorry, can't understand the second question.

Comment: I mean is it require that submit the app in store then after verification we can test it?

Comment: No, you need to test the app before submiting.

Comment: One more question for u suppose I download video with in app.Can I see use it another video app just like We can edit photo from PHOTO.In the same I don't want to open the app the video downloaded by the app will be used in Later is it possible with link given by you?

Comment: An app that is integreated to Music and Video hub can't play a media content that was loaded by another app.